# Is it possible to SET column1 = ARRAY WHERE column2 = ARRAY, and in given order

Tags: arrays, postgresql

This is how my table looks like:

```
  word | key
_______________
       |   helicopter
       |   mamal
       |   cat
       |   bull
       |   bull
       |   bull
       |   mamal
```

And this is the result i want:

```
   word | key
________________
airplane|   helicopter
  bird  |   mamal
  dog   |   cat
  cow   |   bull
  cow   |   bull
  cow   |   bull
  bird  |   mamal
```

I don't want to use 4 updates like this

```
UPDATE table
SET word = 'airplane'
WHERE key = 'helicopter';

UPDATE table
SET word = 'bird'
WHERE key = 'mamal';

UPDATE table
SET word = 'cow'
WHERE key = 'bull';

UPDATE table
SET word = 'dog'
WHERE key = 'cat';
```

but rather one query with number-word pairs defined in one or two arrays... Something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET word = ARRAY['airplane','bird','cow','dog']
WHERE number = ARRAY['helicopter','mamal','bull','cat'];
```

So, the question is: Is it possible to give value 'airplane' to column word WHERE column key = 'helicopter', value 'bird' to column word WHERE column key = 'mamal', and so on, in given order... So i could fill column word depending on column key.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so please excuse possible question flaws, and lots of editting... Thank You

Comment: It could be `update table set letter = (array['a','b','c','d'])[number];`

Comment: `letter = chr(number + ascii('a') - 1)`

Comment: @Abelisto This helps greatly. But i thought that posting a more simplified queston would not make a problem. The fact is that i need to be able to set the letter-number pairs myself... (Letters are words in my real case)

Comment: So you want to update your table using some (key,value) dictionary and the actual question is "How to define such dictionary" (if it not defined yet)?

Comment: Yes, that is the question. Please read my question again, because i have edited it to be more understandable and not over simplified as it was.

Comment: You can try to use my first comment for this: `update table set word = (array['airplane','bird','cow','dog'])[number];`

Comment: Yes, i've tried it and it does the job. But if i had ['helicopter','mamal','bull','cat'] instead of [number]... Does something like: update table set word = (array['airplane','bird','cow','dog'])['helicopter','mamal','bull','cat'];
exist?

Comment: Finally its clear :o) If it is not a problem then you could to create "true" dictionary table (probably temporary) and use it with `update` statement: `update table t set word = d.value from dict_table d where d.key = t.key;`. If it is a problem, then you may to use `JSONB`: `update table t set word = '{"helicopter": "airplane", "mamal": "bird", "bull": "cow","cat": "dog"}'::jsonb->>key`.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot :) That is the answer i sought :) You can answer my question formaly so i could mark it as "answer accepted"...

Thx again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a problem then you could to create "true" dictionary table (probably temporary) and use it with update statement:

```
update table t set 
  word = d.value 
from dict_table d where d.key = t.key;
```

or, using CTE, without creating additional table:

```
with dict_table(key, value) as (values
  ('helicopter','airplane'),
  ('mamal','bird'),
  ...)
update table t set 
  word = d.value 
from dict_table d where d.key = t.key;
```

If it is a problem, then you may to use JSONB:

```
update table t set 
  word = '{
    "helicopter": "airplane", 
    "mamal": "bird", 
    "bull": "cow",
    "cat": "dog"}'::jsonb->>key.
```

Comment: Great! Just to note: i've used JSONB

Answer (score 2):

This will work from PostgreSQL 9.5 on:

```
UPDATE "table"
SET word = (ARRAY['airplane', 'bird', 'cow', 'dog'])[
              array_position(
                 ARRAY['helicopter', 'mamal', 'bull', 'cat'],
                 key::text
              )
           ];
```

Comment: Excuse me if i was unclear. Now i've added example tables of what is in database at the moment and what i want for the result. I hope this helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Ok, that's even simpler.

Comment: And what if i would want to define the letter-number pairs myself? The fact is that i have words in the real case...

Comment: I asked a simplified question thinking that i should not complicate with bunch of long names etc... Sorry for disinformation!

Comment: Well, it's no use asking a simplified question if the real problem has been simplified away. Could you modify it to state your real problem (*words in the real case* seems rather vague), and I can try to answer it.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry. I have edited the question, i hope now it is understandable.

Comment: I've tried it and i get this error: function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist

Comment: You didn't mention that you are using an older version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am sorry, but i use "PostgreSQL 9.5.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 32-bit". And as i see, 9.5 is the newest.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize you are using `varchar`. I added a cast that should make it work.

Comment: Yes, this works also. Thank you for your time and patiens! (I already marked the previous answer as accapted, and now i see that i am not able to mark two answers as accepted.)